# Issues in installing yum-utils on centos 7.4.1708

Tags: centos, yum

My centos version is 7.1.1503. When I tried installing yum-utils using yum-install it's trying the repo http://centos.myfahim.com/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml and other mirrors on centos version 7.4.1708 and got failed. While debugging its mentioned centos 7.4.1708 is deprecated and recommended to go with 7 instead.

Why it's trying with centos 7.4.1708 instead of 7.1 and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got that installed by overriding the version by adding repo details in centos repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d under extras

```
[extras7]
name=New url for centos 7
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/
enabled=1
```